# Two measures power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have one date tables and want to create two measures :

1. Sales
2. Sales last month

so every time customer uses slicer to filter the date 1.Sales shows the output and 2.Sales last month previous month output .

How ?

I'm trying using VAR but I cant manage how

Answer (score 0):

1. create calendar table with formula:

   Calendar = ADDCOLUMNS (
   calendar(firstdate('S'[Date]),lastdate('S'[DATE])),
   "Year", YEAR ( [Date] ),
   "Quarter","Q"&QUARTER([date]),
   "Month", MONTH ( [Date] ),
   "Y&M", YEAR ( [Date] ) * 100 + MONTH ( [Date] ))

> note inside of the formula you can add other columns such as "week", weeknum([date]); also remove columns you don't need.

[image: calendar table]

2. set tables relationship in Model view, it should be one-multiple relation between calendar table to sales table:
   [image: tables relationship]
3. calculate measures:

   sales=sum('sales'[sales])
   sales last month = calculate([sales],dateadd('calendar'[date],-1,month))
4. results as below:
   [image: result]